# Permission denied in Apache instead of 777

Tags: php, apache, grav

I am having a hard time deploying a PHP website built using [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) on CentOS.

Whenever I try to open the website I get 500 Server Error. The logs say:

```
Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Creating directory '/var/www/html/glug_site/cache//compiled/files' failed on error mkdir(): Permission denied' in /var/www/html/glug_site/vendor/rockettheme/toolbox/File/src/File.php:420\nStack trace:\...
```

I followed the guide mentioned [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/troubleshooting/permissions) but it didn't helped.

Then, I did `chmod 777 -R glug_nith/` but still it doesn't work. I even logged into `apache` user using `sudo -u apache bash` to see if I am able to create folders and files inside myapp and I was successful. I tried deleting the `.htaccess` file to see if that would help but it didn't.

I cannot understand instead of having all the permission why its showing permission denied. Also I couldn't find any thing that might be blocking the permission. Please help.

Comment: It's trying to write in the `/var/www/html/glug_site/cache//compiled/files`-folder. Not your `myapp/` folder. And there is a double `//` in that path. Probably a setting that shouldn't start or end with a slash?

Comment: I used the `myapp` to refer to `glug_site`. I will fix it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I found the `//` fishy too. How can I fix it? Any idea?

Comment: try `chmod 777 -R glug_site/cache/`

Comment: @SaurabhSharma No, it didn't worked.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a config of settings file with some paths in it? Seems like there is a `/` too many in the beginning or end in one of those settings.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I manually created the folder `compiled/files` and it stopped complaining for that folder but gave permission denied for other file/folder. So I think `//` is not a problem.

Comment: To be specific, now its giving the error `Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Opening file for writing failed on error fopen(/var/www/html/glug_site/cache//compiled/files/14c9fe43ed2de52eaddb9431486aec95.yaml.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/html/glug_site/vendor/rockettheme/toolbox/File/src/File.php:202\nStack trace` after I manually created the `compiled/files` folders.

Comment: Did you set the correct file permissions on those folder as well, after you created them?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No I didn't, but I just did that now. I set the permission to 777 of new created folders but still the same error.

Comment: @Lokesh Have you tried this: https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/912

Comment: @SaurabhSharma You are awesome. It worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try uncommenting the 12th line in ur .htaccess file

Modify this

```
# RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```